# TypeScript: conditional types and using a boolean parameter to control the return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

How do I rewrite this without overload signatures, using conditional types instead?

```
function foo(returnString: true): string;
function foo(returnString: false): number;
function foo(returnString: boolean) {
  return returnString ? String(Math.random()) : Math.random();
}
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't compile without `as any`:

```
function foo<T extends boolean>(returnString: T): T extends true ? string : number {
  return (returnString ? String(Math.random()) : Math.random()) as any;
}
```

How can I get rid of `as any`?

The error message is super-unhelpful:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? string : number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? string : number'.
```

Comment: Looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929), and they mention in that issue that an `any` cast or overloads are the current workarounds. Additionally in their [June Design Meeting Notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24940) they mention: *Today, a type isn't assignable to a conditional type unless it's another conditional type.*, so it seems they are aware of this and a fix may be coming in the future.

Comment: @CRice Thanks! Before asking my question, I spent quite some time trying to find a corresponding issue, but it hid too well.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not exactly sure why the compiler can't accept this as is (not extremely familiar with TypeScript), but here's what you could do:

```
function foo<T extends boolean>(returnString: T): T extends true ? string : number;
function foo<T extends boolean>(returnString: T): string | number {
  return returnString ? String(Math.random()) : Math.random();
}
```

Basically you separate the declaration (public signature) and the implementation, giving the more accurate signature to the declaration and the broader one to the implementation.

Comment: This works, but I thought conditional types would allow us to get rid of declaration signatures altogether in cases like this.

Comment: My real signature is, of course, more complex than the example. Keeping two copies of it feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your functions like this:

```
export class MyService {

    request(param: false): string; // must a defination;

    request(param: true): number;

    request(param: any): string | number {
        return null;
    }

}
```

borrowed from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts

with typescript 2.8, you can write func like this:

```
function fun<T extends true | false>(t: T): T extends true ? string : number {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling this code? It doesn't seem to be able to work. If so, please add the example which compiles.

Comment: I see. This is just what OP explicitly stated as undesirable.

Comment: sorry, it's my fault, It is a feature of typescript 2.8, you can write like this:

    function fun<T extends true | true>(t: T): T extends true ? string : number {
        return null;
    }

Comment: I've added return statement into your function (like in question) - it doesn't seem to distinguish `true` and `false`. `T extends boolean` holds independently of value.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that issue , and in the fact I did not solved it.
But I found a way to avoid using type any by assigning the conditional return type to a generic. Then can be used instead of any.

```js
function foo<T extends boolean, Z = T extends true ? string : number >(returnString?: T ): Z  {
    if(returnString) {
        return String(Math.random()) as Z ;
    }
    return Math.random() as Z ;
}
```